# I have to select same projectId, Same resource Id rows from the database

Tags: c#, list, datatable, where-clause

I want to select particular `ResourceId` and `projectId` rows from the database.
When passing a list contain some `projectId` and `ResourceId` I get an error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'SyncRms.Services.RequiredData get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= List.Count; i++)
{
    Guid RId = (Guid)List[i].ResourceId;

    // I get the error on this line of code
    var result = db.External_Timesheet.Where(x=>x.ResourceId.Equals(int(List[i].ResourceId))&&x.ProjectId.Equals(List[i].ProjectId));                          
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Entities does not know how to translate the int cast code in to sql, you need to cast it outside the linq query and then use the value in the query, a quick fix for this will be like:

int ResId = int(List[i].ResourceId);

and then use it in your query like

x.ResourceId.Equals(ResId) ....